# What skin will turn the dragons into wolfs?

Tags: overwatch

Hanzo has two wolf skins, I was thinking of getting one, but I don't know what skin will turn the dragons into wolfs. Which one will? Or will both skins turn them into wolfs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for either the **Okami** skin or the **Lone Wolf** skin.

Lone Wolf:

[image]

Okami:

[image]

Either of these skins will turn the twin dragons into a pair of spiraling wolves.